# Accessing an element within a dictionary within in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, http-get

The purpose of this code is to send a http get request and I want to take the value of one of the keys from the the result of the request. As an example I want to get the value of "target", see intended behaviour below:

```
request = request.get(url,auth=(user,password))

all_results = request.text

print(all_results)
>>> {"thing":[{"thing1":1,"thing2":2,"thing3":3,"thing4":4,"thing5":5,"thing6":{"t1":0,"t2":2,"t3":0,"t4":0,"t5":0,},"target":"I WANT THIS"}],"l":{"m":1,"n":1,"o":0}}

x = all_results["thing"][0]["transactions"]

print(x) 
>>> "I WANT THIS"
```

But when i print x, I get an error:

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: Accessing elements of a dictionary (even if they are nested deep inside) is usually covered by tutorials on dictionaries. A question as basic as this indicates that you might find it much more helpful to peruse a tutorial about dictionaries or talk to a tutor, since they will teach you a bunch of related concepts so that you have a broad understanding of the concept, rather than getting an answer to this one specific question on SO.

Answer (score 1):

Use `my_dict["things"][0]["target"]`

Complete Code:

```
mydict = {"things":
        [
            {
                "thing1":"a",
                "thing2":"b",
                "thing3":{
                    "something1":"c",
                    "something2":"d"
                    },
                "target":"I WANT THIS"
            }
        ],
    "somethingelse":"z"
} 

x = mydict ["things"][0]["target"]

print(x)
 
>> I WANT THIS
```

Comment: While code-only answers might answer the question, you could significantly improve the quality of your answer by providing context for your code, 
a reason for why this code works, and some references to documentation for further reading.
From [answer]: _"Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."_

Comment: Thank you. I have realised now that my all_results variable was in fact a string rather than a dictionary because request.text returns a string.

Comment: Try request.json.. Please mark the question as accepted if its helped you.